# Why column name is invalid

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I can run the following query in SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [Sample ID]
FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
```

And it will output a table with values. I want to get the count of row for the table by doing the following:

```
SELECT COUNT([Sample ID]) FROM [database].[dbo].[table] AS [Total]
```

But I get the following error:

`Invalid column name 'Sample ID'.`

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: rename your column and don't name a table `table`

Comment: It would also be good to not name a database "database".

Comment: In the select statement?

Comment: As you can see the first query which gives me a table with result. I am just trying to count how many rows does the column `Sample ID` have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) [TOTAL] FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
```

Comment: Weird. that worked. Why didn't the column name itself didn't work?

Comment: What if [Sample ID] is NULL in some rows?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT([Sample ID]) [TOTAL] FROM [database].[dbo].[table]` should work also.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean

```
SELECT COUNT([Sample ID]) AS [Total] FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
```

Answer (score 1):

move alias to column level, check column if exist, check table if exist and also search before asking basic question..

SELECT COUNT([Sample ID]) **AS [Total]** FROM [database].[dbo].[table]

Answer (score -2):

Your column name shouldn't have a space in it.  Is that an actual column name?

Comment: As you can see the first query which gives me a table with result. I am just trying to count how many rows dows the column `Sample ID` have.

Comment: There is nothing inherently incorrect about using space characters in the name of a database field.  It can be inconvenient, not it's not incorrect.

Comment: @STLDeveloper It is bad practice, though, and should be avoided.

Comment: @ChrisWillard - says who?